# The previous and next button in fancybox are interfering with the play button of a vimeo video when it is set to display as gallery

Tags: fancybox, gallery, vimeo

I have already tried tweaking the fancybox stylesheet but can't seem to move the hover area of the previous and next button so that it does not interfere with the play button of a vimeo video. I don't know if the problem can be solved by modifying the javascript file but I really don't have the knowledge to do so. Here is the css code of the fancybox stylesheet:

```
#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 35%;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
background: transparent url('blank.gif');
z-index: 1102;
display: none;
}

#fancybox-left {
left: 0px;
}

#fancybox-right {
right: 0px;
}

#fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: -9999px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-top: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1102;
display: block;
}

#fancybox-left-ico {
background-image: url('fancybox.png');
background-position: -40px -30px;
}

#fancybox-right-ico {
background-image: url('fancybox.png');
background-position: -40px -60px;
}

#fancybox-left:hover, #fancybox-right:hover {
visibility: visible; /* IE6 */
}

#fancybox-left:hover span {
left: 20px;

}

#fancybox-right:hover span {
left: auto;
right: 20px;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to modify the hover areas for the previous and next buttons when using fancybox.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make the containing divs shorter as I have just done, so the prev/next arrow hover areas finish just above the Vimeo controls

```
#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
height: 86%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this with:

```
#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
    width: 0%;
}
```

I put this selector in my own stylesheet which I loaded after Fancybox's.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to mess with original fancybox css file.

What you can do is to crop the navigation arrows to their size so the next/prev area don't cover a whole area on both sides of the box.

AFTER you linked the fancybox css file, add this inline css declaration:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #fancybox-left,
 #fancybox-right {
  width: 30px; height: 30px; top: 45%
 }

 #fancybox-left:hover span,
 #fancybox-left-ico{
  left: -10px;
 }

 #fancybox-right:hover span,
 #fancybox-right-ico {
  right: -10px;
  left: auto;
 }
</style>
```

This is for fancybox v1.3.x

Comment: do you know how to use it in fancybox v2? could you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867874/the-previous-and-next-button-of-my-fancybox-are-too-big?lq=1)

Comment: I've tried it, add a new Css and linked it after fancybox css. Then I also add the javascript. but the next and previous button area are still so big

Comment: @Mark I thought you wanted the nav buttons not blocking the video controls http://jsfiddle.net/zgek0LdL/

Comment: sorry, my problem was I have an iFrame which linked to layout. The layout is needed to display each data. So it would have next and previous button to view another data. But the next and previous button are too big that they cover almost all of my iFrame, so that I cant edit the text inside the iFrame (behind the previous button)