# The previous and next button of my fancybox are too big

Tags: c#, fancybox-2

I have a `fancybox` which have next and previous buttons inside it. But the previous and next button area is too big that it covers my textbox on the fancybox. I have tried some suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492999/the-previous-and-next-button-in-fancybox-are-interfering-with-the-play-button-of).

```
#fancybox-left, #fancybox-right {
    width: 0%;
}
```

But it doesnt working. The area for buttons is still as big as before. Seems like it was for fancybox version 1. I am using fancybox version 2 right now. Any suggestion how should I do the `css` for next and previous button in `fancybox 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works in Fancybox v1.3

```
<style type="text/css">
 #fancybox-left,
 #fancybox-right {
  width: 30px; height: 30px; top: 45%
 }

 #fancybox-left:hover span,
 #fancybox-left-ico{
  left: -10px;
 }

 #fancybox-right:hover span,
 #fancybox-right-ico {
  right: -10px;
  left: auto;
 }
</style>
```